# What is the required vaccination percentage of a 330M population to achieve herd immunity?

Tags: covid-19

As I understand it, the idea is that the density of viable hosts for a pathogens is reduced so as to effectively halt infections.

[image]
The question is posed because ABC news indicates that nearly 1/3 of the US population would not COVID19 vaccinate. Assuming this is true: what is the likelihood of achieving herd immunity with 2/3 of the population?  and why?

Is there a minimum percentage that will produce herd immunity?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a minimum percentage that will produce herd immunity?

Answer from the [WHO](https://www.who.int/news-room/q-a-detail/herd-immunity-lockdowns-and-covid-19#:%7E:text=The%20percentage%20of%20people%20who,a%20population%20to%20be%20vaccinated.) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20201104034709/https://www.who.int/news-room/q-a-detail/herd-immunity-lockdowns-and-covid-19)):

> The percentage of people who need to have antibodies in order to achieve herd immunity against a particular disease varies with each disease. For example, herd immunity against measles requires about 95% of a population to be vaccinated. The remaining 5% will be protected by the fact that measles will not spread among those who are vaccinated. For polio, the threshold is about 80%.

The estimation of the threshold for COVID-19 herd immunity is 70% according to the [Mayo Clinic](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/coronavirus/in-depth/herd-immunity-and-coronavirus/art-20486808) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20201104034707/https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/coronavirus/in-depth/herd-immunity-and-coronavirus/art-20486808)):

> Even if infection with the COVID-19 virus creates long-lasting immunity, a large number of people would have to become infected to reach the herd immunity threshold. **Experts estimate that in the U.S., 70% of the population — more than 200 million people — would have to recover from COVID-19 to halt the epidemic**.